# What are the implications of the ffmpeg / libav fork for users?

Tags: ffmpeg

The ffmpeg project got forked:
http://libav.org/
http://ffmpeg.org/

libav has already been added to the ubuntu repositories:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libav

What are the implications of the ffmpeg / libav fork for a ubuntu user?

Answer (score 5):

Please read this, interesting analysis of the situation in 2012: 
http://blog.pkh.me/p/13-the-ffmpeg-libav-situation.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Both sides presented their point to Ubuntu Technical Board in an apparent attempt to sell own variant [1].

'libav' won, which is not surprising since Debian/Ubuntu package maintainer is one of them.

As of Dec 18, 2011 'ffmpeg' has at least one point where it works, and 'libav' doesn't [2].

1. https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/technical-board/2011-May/000891.html
2. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libav/+bug/905753

Comment: FWIW ffmpeg appear to be incorporating all changes made in libav, and seem to have the stronger product.