# Why can't I watch video after installing the original ffmpeg fork from Jon Severinson's PPA?

Tags: video, dependencies, ffmpeg, libav

I just installed the Jon Severinsson ffmpeg PPA, and I cant watch any video and get audio only, I get a need *extra plugins needed install?* and then *packaged dependencies could no be resolved* . Here are the screenshots, any help?

[image: screen-1]

[image: screen-2]

Comment: If you open a Terminal window (`Ctrl`+`Alt`+`T`) and run `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg`, then **edit your question** to include all the text starting on the line where you entered that second command, this will present technical information about what went wrong in a more complete and readable manner. After pasting it into your post, you should select it and use the `<$>` tool in the editing toolbar so that it is formatted correctly. (When you run those `sudo ...` commands, and you enter your password, you won't see any change; that's OK.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Jon Severinson's *ffmpeg* is NOT Ubuntu's *ffmpeg!***

- Last year, some of the *ffmpeg* developers split off and started their own version ("fork") of *ffmpeg*, called ***libav***. For various reasons, Ubuntu ended up choosing *libav* as the version to include in Ubuntu 12.04. [See this question for more info.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32189/what-are-the-implications-of-the-ffmpeg-libav-fork-for-users?rq=1)
- Both *ffmpeg* and *libav* are actively developed, in parallel, right now. Jon's PPA contains the latest **original** *ffmpeg* packages, not the *libav* ones (which are in the official Ubuntu repository)
- Both sets of packages have different, incompatible and confusing versioning schemes -- and this is a problem because they also share some of the same components, dependencies, etc. due to their shared heritage. *libav* **0.8.x** is as "new" as *ffmpeg* **0.10.x**!
- Right now, Ubuntu applications are set to depend on the *libav* versions of software.
- But when you install Jon's *ffmpeg*, Software Center/apt gets confused because the audio/video player needs dependencies, but **different versions** of those are already installed!
- Bottom line: if you install Jon's *ffmpeg*, you have to be prepared to separately install or build from source your preferred audio/video players. *ffmpeg* and *libav* cannot co-exist on an Ubuntu installation at this time (unless you install one of them manually).
- So, unless you need some particular feature only implemented by *ffmpeg*, **stick to *libav*** since it's the officially supported fork and is as new and actively developed as *ffmpeg*.

Comment: thanks for the editing my question,and the explanation for the fork, had i known earlier, thanks.

Comment: It would be cool if the same PPA that provides *ffmpeg* also provided PPA versions of some of the most commonly used libraries, utilities, and video players that must be build from source against either *ffmpeg* and *libav*.

Comment: @Eliah Kagan  yes thanks both of you, it solved the problem, thanks again.

Comment: @izx thanks it solverd the problem, you both (eliah) are awesome, very quick replies.

Comment: @GabrielRojas You should definitely [**accept izx's answer**](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1137/how-do-i-accept-an-answer) then, so it's clear to people searching for help that this problem has a known solution (and what the solution is).

Comment: @EliahKagan, it's an unholy mess -- Jon claims binaries won't break -- but packages certainly do. Trying to replicate OP's case -- install ffmpeg and then install `gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg` fails [with this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1044006/), just because of the difference in version numbering. But yes, I agree someone (if not Jon) should look into providing common packages/frameworks that won't break if ffmpeg is installed.

Answer (score 2):

Getting the real ffmpeg to work right is simple:

See **[this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/373509/165265)** -- and it auto-updates using the Jon Severinsson PPA.

@izx correctly points out that ffmpeg can not coexist with libav, but the advice in his last bullet, "*...stick to libav since it's the officially supported fork and is as new and actively developed as ffmpeg,*" may not be best. At least in Precise, I find the real ffmpeg superior.

The answer to your question, @Gabriel Rojas (cc @nitstorm, @Eliah Kagan), is that one can not simply add the ffmpeg repo and update. The train wreck shown in the OP is to be expected if this is done. Instead, **libav must first be purged**, THEN the real ffmpeg can be installed, and should work without error. See [**the above link**](https://askubuntu.com/a/373509/165265) for step-by-step commands.

Since doing this a couple days ago, have pushed the new ffmpeg hard -- and found it flawless.

---

Last activity here was some time ago, but this thread comes up high in the search rank so wanted to update with a solution that works.