# How do I uninstall ffmpeg?

Tags: uninstall, ffmpeg

I am using ubuntu 12.04. I had installed ffmpeg a while ago (so don't clearly remember whether it was from source or repo). Now, I am unable to uninstall it. I have tried the followin:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove ffmpeg

$ sudo apt-get purge ffmpeg
```

I tried to find ffmpeg directory by issuing the following command:

```
$ find / -name 'ffmpeg' -type d
```

This gave me /home//ffmpeg. When I changed to the directory, I found ffmpeg and ffmpeg1, however "sudo make uninstall" didn't work for both the places and threw an error "make: *** No rule to make target `uninstall'.  Stop.". That, I suppose, would mean that it was not the source from which ffmpeg was (if) compiled.

When I issue the following command:

```
$ffmpeg -version
```

I get:

```
ffmpeg version 0.8.3-4:0.8.3-0ubuntu0.12.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the Libav developers
  built on Jun 12 2012 16:37:58 with gcc 4.6.3
*** THIS PROGRAM IS DEPRECATED ***
This program is only provided for compatibility and will be removed in a future release. Please use avconv instead.
ffmpeg 0.8.3-4:0.8.3-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
libavutil    51. 22. 1 / 51. 22. 1
libavcodec   53. 35. 0 / 53. 35. 0
libavformat  53. 21. 0 / 53. 21. 0
libavdevice  53.  2. 0 / 53.  2. 0
libavfilter   2. 15. 0 /  2. 15. 0
libswscale    2.  1. 0 /  2.  1. 0
libpostproc  52.  0. 0 / 52.  0. 0
```

Comment: Someone will probably post a one-line command that will fix it for you, but you might try using Synaptic and mark ffmpeg for 'complete removal'. This usually works pretty well for removing programs.

Comment: @TomBrossman: Thanks for  the help ! I shall try your suggestion and shall update the result here.

Comment: @TomBrossman: In the Synaptics Manager, when I searched for "ffmpeg", the installed packages that appear are:
chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra, 
librtmp0, 
winff, 
gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg. Should I remove them all ?

Comment: No Idea. It isn't going to break your system so try it. If you have audio playback issues just re-add them.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For reasons [discussed in this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151494/why-cant-i-watch-video-after-installing-the-original-ffmpeg-fork-from-jon-sever/151508#151508), the "ffmpeg" in Ubuntu 12.04 is actually provided by the `libav-tools` package; that's why removing the *ffmpeg* package seemingly does nothing.

To really remove it:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove libav-tools
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove
```

> Note: The contents of the *2.2 kB* ffmpeg package deb file as provided by libav simply pulls in libav as dependencies...

Comment: Thanks ! That worked. And +1 for the link that made me understand more about Ubuntu 12.04's ffmpeg

Comment: hi @ish, is this still true for Ubuntu 16.04?