# How to record video streamed to Firefox

Tags: video, screencast

I'm using Ubuntu Precise 64 bit. Is there an app which will capture video & audio from a TV programme being played on my PC? I'm thinking of the video coming on Demand. PS by capture, I mean record to disk.

Answer (score 1):

None of above apps work for me. I've got ffmpeg (command line program) to do the job. I was not able to use the Ubuntu supplied version of ffmpeg, which is actually avconv, as it won't accept the pulse parameter. So I installed the 'proper' ffmpeg using
[How to replace avconv with (the real) ffmpeg and have it work right?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/373322/how-to-replace-avconv-with-the-real-ffmpeg-and-have-it-work-right)

and that did the job. I'm going to write a Gambas3 app to do the job with a GUI.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options for this, what you want is a "screencast". For this task there are **several** (yes, redundancy) tools:

- RecordMyDesktop
- Kazam
- Instambul
- deskscribe
- kx11grab
- MORE

Just look for them in the Ubuntu Software Center take one, test it and love it!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I've previously tried RecordMyDesktop but it replays the video without sound. Presumably this is to allow you to add your own sound e.g. when making your own Youtube video when you would add your commentary through a microphone. However, I've just now used Kazam which did what I wanted. It allows recording of the audio (onto a .mp4 video file) using 'Monitor of Built-in Audio Analogue Stereo'  for the 'Audio Source 1' parameter.

Comment: kazam should do it but it always crashes. I've also tried to install eidete but install fails. I've tried using CLI ffmpeg/avconv but it objects to "-f pulse" parameter which I wanted to use for reasonable quality audio recording. So I followed advice in http://askubuntu.com/questions/373322/how-to-replace-avconv-with-the-real-ffmpeg-and-have-it-work-right to install the proper ffmpeg (rather than avconv) and "-f pulse" now works.

Comment: @JohnRose if my answer solves your question, please mark it as accepted.