# ffmpeg how to output images from a video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, png

I want to extract images from a video 
I want thous images to be extracted from specific time for example 0:30 1:15 1:45 and I would love them to be in PNG format as well

Thank you in advanced

**Update**
Thank you rechengehirn and Rmano Sadly I can not except both of your answer and I selected it randomly sorry for that but  I thought it would be fair like that because both of your answers work so Thank you again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
ffmpeg -i input_movie.mp4 -ss 00:00:05 -f image2 -vframes 1 imagename.png
```

Where the options are:

```
-i              > The input video file
-ss  00:00:05   > Start at Second 5 of movie
-f image2       > Force image output
-vframes 1      > Set the number of video frames to record
```

You can read the ffmpeg documentation on: http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html

Comment: `-f image2` is not needed. It is usually used in scripts where the output file name may be ambiguous to ffmpeg.

Answer (score 1):

I am using a [static build of a recent `ffmpeg`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/373322/how-to-replace-avconv-with-the-real-ffmpeg-and-have-it-work-right/373328#373328), but it should not matter. 
What I use is

```
ffmpeg -i videoin.avi -ss 30 -r 1 -t 1 myimage.png
```

that skips the first 30 seconds, then use a framerate of 1 frame/sec and creates images for 1 second.

Googling around I found this: http://linuxers.org/tutorial/how-extract-images-video-using-ffmpeg with a bit more options.

Comment: `-vframes 1` or `-frames:v 1` is usually recommended instead of `-r 1 -t 1`.