# What are the top video and audio converting software available for Linux?

Tags: software-recommendation, conversion

**What is important is the functionality of the software** Simply the software should recognize as much formats as possible. **It should contain lots and lots of conversion options;** which basically means that I can convert to as much file types as possible. and of course its bugs should be little in number and trivial. It should have strong support from the community. It's *preferable* that it would have a good and easy to use GUI.

I don't prefer a software that can deal with both audio and video. I prefer 2 software where each is specified for a certain job.

I use the windows programs AVS audio and video converters. I need Linux software that are as powerful as those. upto this moment I switch back to windows so that I can convert my media.

Comment: This is clearly an opinion. I'm not sure that the software-recommendation tag is for this purpose. Top and last program doesn't exist. This depends clearly from what you want to do with it. I can suggest 4-5 programs I have used, but do not ask for which of them is the best, because it would be an opinion based answer.

Comment: I think I've specified what I'm exactly asking about. are 4 lines not enough? ...If you've noticed I'm not asking about one software. read the title again. The word "software" can be plural. ... Why not tell me about the 5 software. I'd be happy to know.

Comment: If you want to go without a GUI, in my opinion `ffmpeg` is still the most powerful tool around: http://askubuntu.com/questions/373322/how-to-replace-avconv-with-the-real-ffmpeg-and-have-it-work-right . You can download and install the static version which is hassles-free.

Comment: ?? how come my question is "too broad". what else do you need to know??!

Comment: As long as any answer is *correct*, the question is not a place for Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: please check this link... [Windows Software Alternatives in Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/389228/what-default-windows-software-alternatives-does-ubuntu-have/389230#389230)

Comment: @braiam any question with the tag `software-recommendation` would go like that. How can you have a wrong "recommendation"?!

@hash thanks!!

Comment: http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/7947/169736

Comment: I asked for 2 closely related particular types of software with 4 lines of specifications and details! It won't generate a list. He asked for an indefinite number of software alternatives with no specifications at all. How do you compare me to him? ... anyways his question has a different goal. He is sharing his knowledge. It's something good for his question to be closed so that the focus is on his answer! I'm asking for popularly used software. Now that you've closed the question I'd never know what's popular.

Answer (score 3):

Go for [Handbrake](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/HandBrake).

I use it by myself and did not experience any bug so far. GUI provides a good overview and also lets you get into detail. It is used for video conversion, mainly for DVD -> File but can also be used to convert different formats.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:stebbins/handbrake-releases
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install handbrake-gtk
```

You might want to check the following two lists for the software that fills your needs best:

List of [Videoconverters](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Videodateien_umwandeln) and
[Audioconverters](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Audiodateien_umwandeln).

Comment: is it an audio or video conversion software? or maybe does it do both?

Comment: There is still no version for 13.10 in that PPA. So if you have a 13.10 installation you need to manually install it: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/10/install-handbrake-in-ubuntu-13-10-saucy/

Comment: I am pretty sure I installed it from PPA on my 13.10. I can be wrong tho.