# How do I install ffmpeg?

Tags: ppa, ffmpeg, codecs, 14.04, libav

I need to install the package ffmpeg because I am trying to install subsonic server on my new Ubuntu Gnome 14.04

When I try:

`apt-get install ffmpeg`

I get:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ffmpeg : Depends: libavcodec54 (>= 7:1.2.5~) but it is not going to be installed or
                   libavcodec-extra-54 (>= 7:1.2.5~) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libavdevice53 (>= 7:1.2.5~) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libavfilter3 (>= 7:1.2.5~) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libavformat54 (>= 7:1.2.5~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have tried
`apt-get -f install ffmpeg`
`apt-get install --fix-broken`
`apt-get autoclean`
`apt-get autoremove`

With no luck at all. I found a repository and added it to my sources via:
`add-apt-repository ppa:jon-severinsson/ffmpeg`

With still no luck.  I found this question [Is FFmpeg missing from the official repositories in 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/432542/is-ffmpeg-missing-from-the-official-repositories-in-14-04)  which led me to try this:

`apt-get install libav-tools`

which resulted in this:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libav-tools : Depends: ffmpeg (>= 7:0.10~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I also have made sure my "Software & Updates" have all the proper repositiories checked off, namely all 4 on the "Ubuntu Software" tab, and all on the "Other Software" tab with the exception of the second one (Canonical Partners Source Code).  I also have these checked off as well per instructions supplied on the page they lead to:
`http://ppa.launchpad.net/jon-severinsson/ffmpeg/ubuntu saucy main`
`http://ppa.launchpad.net/jon-severinsson/ffmpeg/ubuntu trusty main`

None of this works.  How can I install ffmpeg? Or if I cannot install it, what do I need to install to replace its functionality?

Comment: Can you install the dependencies manually?

Comment: @the_Seppi you mean dependencies such as libavcodec54? that doesn't work either.  Or do you mean something else?

Comment: when I try to `apt-get install avconv` - this package is not found.

Comment: one more thing, I just  fresh installed 14.04 today. THis was one of the first things I tried to install on it.

Comment: The prblem is the "big split" between ffmpeg and avconv, that makes almost impossible to cleanly install the two. Maybe http://askubuntu.com/questions/373322/how-to-replace-avconv-with-the-real-ffmpeg-and-have-it-work-right can help. I really went the way of installing a static build, works like a charm in 13.10: http://askubuntu.com/a/373328/16395

Comment: okay I followed those directions, but where do I go from here? I simply just have ffmpeg in a directory `~/bin`, ran the command `./ffmpeg` and it just provides configuration methods, kind of like a man page almost. @Rmano

Comment: Now you just have to install the package that uses it. Btw, for system packages, is better to put the executable in `/usr/local/bin/`. Each application will have a different way to find the `ffmpeg` binary --- I known nothing about subsonic. Moreover, some applications use the library and not the binary; in that case the static binary solution is not useful at all, you should try the other solution, but you're on your own. Debian and Ubuntu have chosen to go with libav, not with ffmpeg. Info here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libav/+bug/1263278

Comment: @rmano problem is I can't install libav either, I got errors on that too (see above).  I ffmpeg will not install on 14.04 I've tried everything (I think).

Comment: Is there an alternative package or is this functionality of what ffmpeg offers just not going to be offered on 14.04?

Comment: Really, I do not know --- I use ffmpeg by command line and nothing more, and the static build works for me. But I suppose that 14.04 will still stay with libav (notice that libav name is used in the two projects, but are different things). In debian the discussion is still on https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=729203