# Very slow conversion with avconv (libav) - Trusty Tahr 14.04?

Tags: media, conversion, avconv, libav

Yesterday I installed the latest Kubuntu release 14.04. So I meet a little problems with the media conversions. The old FFmpeg is finally replaced with avconv which is in the libav-tools library. Till now i was using ffmpeg and every mp4 or flv to mp3 conversion was very fast. For example if one file around 5mins length was converted for ~20secs, now the same file is converted ~3-4-5 times slower. I read everywhere, but could not find where is the problem.. Is there any cure about that?

Best regards :)

Comment: Short of http://askubuntu.com/questions/373322/how-to-replace-avconv-with-the-real-ffmpeg-and-have-it-work-right ... you can check if the static ffmpeg is still faster to rule out some other problem.

Comment: Yes. I already been downloaded the static ffmpeg version because my other question here, it works faster and after all i'm using it for now. But my question is about avconv.. I doubt it's something normal to be so slower than ffmpeg.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So the answer is in one simple parameter **-vn** which disable video recording for the output which is actually unneeded when making conversion from mp4(probably every video file) to mp3.

‘-vn (output)’ 
Disable video recording.

In my case I'm using Download Helper for Firefox. I made custom mp3 conversion where added this parameter there and now everything is even faster than ffmpeg.

Comment: The -vn option has to be provided after the input is specified. Otherwise it doesn't seem to have an effect.

Answer (score 2):

It would be well worth experimenting a little with the avconv `-threads` option. For example when transcoding from mp4 to mp3 file, as you mentioned, try something like the following:

```
avconv -i input.mp4 -threads auto -vn -c:a libmp3lame -qscale:a 3 output.mp3
```

The `-threads` option also accepts an integer so you could experiment a little with this. If this makes no difference the eventual answer is probably that your copy of FFmpeg encodes faster than your copy of avconv. Try using [the time utility](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_time.htm) to quantify the difference...

Comment: Yes, this line makes a difference. For example same file converted with ffmpeg done for 0m17.189s and avconv for 0m5.816s.. But the option which makes the difference wasn't -threads but the -vn. I take a look into avconv documentation and found -vn is kinda disabling video recording for the output.                                                              ‘-vn (output)’

    Disable video recording.

Comment: Yes, I thought you were talking about conversion to mp3?

Comment: Yes.. Generally I'm converting media files from mp4 to mp3 using download helper in Firefox. Sometimes using Winff or such a software.

Comment: So now I was testing conversion with avconv through "Download helper" and everything is blazing fast now without loss of quality. I just made custom mp3 conversation where I added "-vn" parameter in the parameters section. I'm cool now :) Thank you!

Comment: Great news! So if you could find the 'best answer' button-thingy this question + thread will be complete :)