# ffmpeg: installing from repository or compiling from source?

Tags: compiling, ffmpeg

When googling for "install ffmpeg ubuntu" the first link I've got was https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide, so I followed it, and unfortunutely got some errors during ffmpeg compilation, on last steps.

Then I've typed `apt-get install ffmpeg` and everything worked. 
My questions are below:

1) Is there any sense compiling when we have binaries in the repo?

1a) (Useless complain: why on earth Google gives compile method first? )

2) Have I spoiled everything with my unsuccessful compilation? I've removed source and build directories, but now I'm not sure if my ffmpeg works correctly. How can I check?? :(

Answer (score 3):

> got some errors during ffmpeg compilation, on last steps

Do you remember what the errors were? Is there a `ffmpeg` binary in `~/bin`?

> 1) Is there any sense compiling when we have binaries in the repo?

Yes:

- Ubuntu (at least until 14.04 I believe) offered a [fake "`ffmpeg`" from a fork](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9477756/1109017). It's not from FFmpeg! This makes some users unhappy and some users feel misled.
- The fake version (and also `avconv`) is buggy and lacks many features.
- FFmpeg development is [very active](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=shortlog).
- Compiling gives you the choice to customize the build the way you want it and to suit your needs. For example you can encode with libfdk_aac which is a great AAC encoder.
- All of the guides, articles, and tutorials in the [FFmpeg Wiki](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/) are for `ffmpeg` from FFmpeg and not guaranteed to work with any third-party counterfeits.

If you want some benefits of using a recent, real `ffmpeg` without needing to compile then you can download a static build from the [FFmpeg Download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html#LinuxBuilds) page. No installation necessary: you just download, exract, and run. It has most of the useful features, but lacks x11grab support (for screen grabbing) and also lacks a few useful encoders.

> 2) Have I spoiled everything with my unsuccessful compilation?

No. The guide is meant to be non-intrusive and non-interfering. See [Reverting Changes Made by This Guide](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide#RevertingChangesMadebyThisGuide) if you wanted to undo everything.

> I've removed source and build directories, but now I'm not sure if my ffmpeg works correctly. How can I check?? :(

Enter `ffmpeg` in your console. If the first line contains:

- `FFmpeg developers` then you're using your compiled version.
- `Libav developers` then you're using the imitation from the repository.

Comment: See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/373322/how-to-replace-avconv-with-the-real-ffmpeg-and-have-it-work-right

Comment: Forgot to mention. The `~/bin` directory is empty.

Comment: @Dan Then I assume it failed during `configure` (possibly due to previous failure of compilation of any required external library) or `make`, but it is only a guess without any actual error messages.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are fine, the failure to complie did not break anything.

Second, it is always best to install from the repositories if at all possible. If you need an alternate version or fratures, use a ppa

Last, who knows why that pageis so high in google =)