# How do I get rid of ffmpeg `WARNING: library configuration mismatch` message?

Tags: 15.10, ffmpeg, avconv

I have been using `avconv` without issue, however since upgrading to 15.10 and switching to `ffmpeg`, I have a `library configuration mismatch` warning in my script output.

This is my command to rip CDs for my iPod and Fiio X5 Mk2.

```
#!/bin/bash

cdparanoia -Bv
for f in ./*.wav; do avconv -i "$f" -acodec alac "${f%.*}.m4a"; done
eject
ls
```

When I replaced `avconv` with `ffmpeg` I now see `WARNING: library configuration mismatch` in the middle of the output:

```
ffmpeg version 2.7.3-0ubuntu0.15.10.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.2.1 (Ubuntu 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) 20151010
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.15.10.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-openal --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-libssh --enable-libsoxr --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv --enable-libx265
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch
  avcodec     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.15.10.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-openal --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-libssh --enable-libsoxr --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv --enable-libx265 --enable-version3 --disable-doc --disable-programs --disable-avdevice --disable-avfilter --disable-avformat --disable-avresample --disable-postproc --disable-swscale --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libvo_aacenc --enable-libvo_amrwbenc
  libavutil      54. 27.100 / 54. 27.100
  libavcodec     56. 41.100 / 56. 41.100
  libavformat    56. 36.100 / 56. 36.100
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 16.101 /  5. 16.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.100 /  1.  2.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.0 : stereo
Input #0, wav, from './track01.cdda.wav':
  Duration: 00:02:36.20, bitrate: 1411 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1411 kb/s
Output #0, ipod, to './track01.cdda.m4a':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.36.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: alac (alac / 0x63616C61), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.41.100 alac
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (pcm_s16le (native) -> alac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
size=   16226kB time=00:02:36.22 bitrate= 850.9kbits/s   
video:0kB audio:16219kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.046357%
```

Checking other sites suggests I have installed `ffmpeg` on an early version of Ubuntu where `avconv` was the default, but this wasn't the case here.

Can anyone suggest a resolution for me?

Comment: Check http://askubuntu.com/questions/373322/how-to-replace-avconv-with-the-real-ffmpeg-and-have-it-work-right

Comment: The library mismatch warning  is due to the use of the 'extra' packages/packaging. It's benign & can be ignored

Comment: Is there any way to hide the terminal spam without removing the `libavcodec-ffmpeg-extra56` package?

Comment: I found a way; although this doesn't answer the original question, which uses a bash script, I put `for i in ffmpeg ffplay ffprobe ffserver; do alias $i="$i -hide_banner"; done` in my .bashrc file.

Comment: Launchpad bug for this warning message: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ffmpeg-extra/+bug/730159

Comment: @Hitechcomputergeek I wish I had seen your comment sooner.  Considering this is only a "warning" and can safely be ignored, knowing about that command-line switch is necessary for so ignoring.

Answer (score 18):

To fix this remove the following package:

```
sudo apt remove libavcodec-ffmpeg-extra56
```

Apt will remove the package and replace it with `libavcodec-ffmpeg56` resulting in `ffmpeg` no longer output a warning message.

For details on `libavcodec-ffmpeg-extra56` package and why it is likely no needed, see: https://askubuntu.com/a/847566/8570

Comment: it resolved same issue in ubuntu 16.04 as well.

Comment: In ubuntu 17.10, this has become libavcodec-extra57 / libavcodec-extra. Amazing that this is still a thing.

Comment: At the risk of upsetting the Ubuntu Police: This also worked on Mint 18. (Great answer, BTW—The quick fix, the explanation, and the reference link. Thank you.)

Comment: The comment of @DavClark is still valid for Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Thanks @DavClark! It works on ubuntu 18.04. I get rid of the warning via `sudo apt remove libavcodec-extra57`.

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04 i get 'Unable to locate package libavcodec-ffmpeg-extra56'  
So it seems the version to remove is 58

Comment: On 20.04 remove ``libavcodec-extra58``. Had to reinstall ffmpeg after removing that.

Answer (score 12):

Adding what worked for me personally (Ubuntu 20.10) because this is one of the first results when searching for this error, and it's been making me mad for the past couple days:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall libavcodec58 libavdevice58 libavfilter7 libavformat58 libavresample4 libavutil56 libpostproc55 libswresample3 libswscale5
```

I didn't even need to reinstall FFmpeg.

Comment: You are a star! This worked for me on Mint 20.2, but the earlier answers here didn't. Thank you!

Comment: I confirm this answer is the only one that worked for me on Mint 20.3 as well. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 11):

On Ubuntu 18.04:

```
sudo apt remove libavcodec-extra57
```

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu 22.04 I just had to install `libavcodec58`. It warned that it would remove `libavcodec-extra` and `libavcodec-extra58`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your libs built from ffmpeg source and libs in your system(/usr/lib/ or /usr/local/lib/) are in conflict.
So

```
find . -name "avcodec"
```

If libavcodec.so.* in /usr/local/lib, /usr/lib/, /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu or /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu, please replace them with the libs built from ffmpeg source and create soft links.

```
cp -r /the/path/to/ffmpeg/build/lib/* /usr/local/lib/
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so.59.18.100 /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so.59
```