# What's the difference between libavcodec-ffmpeg-extra56 and libavcodec-ffmpeg56? Which should I install?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

As the title says - What's the difference between libavcodec-ffmpeg-extra56 and libavcodec-ffmpeg56? Which should I install?

I'm using kdenlive but auditioning some other non-linear video editors. Does it matter which of these packages is installed, presumably one is for ffmpeg and one is for the Ubuntu bawdlerised version (or is it avconv now?)?

Advice please?

Edit, from [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libavcodec&searchon=names&suite=xenial&section=all):

> Package libavcodec-ffmpeg-extra56
>
> ```
> xenial (16.04LTS) (libs): FFmpeg library with **additional** de/encoders for audio/video codecs [universe]
> 7:2.8.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 [security]: amd64 i386
> 7:2.8.6-1ubuntu2 [ports]: arm64 armhf powerpc ppc64el s390x
> ```
>
> Package libavcodec-ffmpeg56
>
> ```
> xenial (16.04LTS) (libs): FFmpeg library with de/encoders for audio/video codecs - runtime files [universe]
> 7:2.8.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 [security]: amd64 i386
> 7:2.8.6-1ubuntu2 [ports]: arm64 armhf powerpc ppc64el s390x
> ```

If you look at the files ([plain](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libavcodec-ffmpeg56/filelist), [extra](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libavcodec-ffmpeg-extra56/filelist)) the only difference appears to be the file in `/usr/share/lintian/overrides/`. The `.so` files are identically named and versioned.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Why extra?

Due to the licenses of the external libraries involved some components were split into libavcodec-extra and libavfilter-extra.

---

## libavcodec-extra

As of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS "Focal", *libavcodec-extra* adds some additional encoders and decoders for the outdated AMR audio format which was used in old phones. There is no reason to install *libavcodec-extra* unless you need to encode AMR.

**Encoders:**

- `libopencore_amrnb` - Adaptive Multi-Rate NarrowBand ([AMR-NB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_Multi-Rate_audio_codec)).
- `libvo_amrwbenc` - Adaptive Multi-Rate WideBand ([AMR-WB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_Multi-Rate_Wideband)).

**Decoders:**

*libavcodec-extra* additionally adds two additional AMR decoders:

- `libopencore_amrnb` for AMR-NB
- `libopencore_amrwb` for AMR-WB

But these decoders are not very useful as FFmpeg can decode AMR-NB and AMR-WB by itself via the built-in decoders `anr_nb` and `amr_wb`.

---

## libavfilter-extra

The *libavfilter-extra* package adds two minor, niche filters:

- [lensfun](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#lensfun) for camera lens distortion correction.
- [ocr](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#ocr) for Optical Character Recognition.

Comment: Thanks for that, it's a bit strange that the packages have the same version of `libavcodec-ffmpeg.so.56.60.100` (for me on xenial), presumably the encoders you mention are somehow "housed" in the only differing (non meta-data) file the one in the `lintian/overrides` folder? Do you have a citation for this info?

Comment: @pbhj The versions should be the same: those refer to the [FFmpeg major, minor, micro version numbers](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/index.html). I don't know and didn't investigate the specifics of how Ubuntu packaged these. Info citation: `ffmpeg -codecs > default.txt` (with libavcodec-ffmpeg56), `ffmpeg -codecs > extra.txt` (with libavcodec-ffmpeg-extra56), `diff default.txt extra.txt`.

Comment: Thanks again. Seems close to criminal to me to give two different files the same name and version.

Comment: @pbhj I'm not sure what you mean by same name. The two packages come from the same source code so the major, minor, and micro versions should be the same. The actual names of the packages and the reasoning for splitting libavcodec into two packages was a Debian packaging decision; likely due to the particular licenses used by these external libraries.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `libavcodec-ffmpeg-extra56` is an Ubuntu Package, that may have been renamed or reworked specifically for Ubuntu.  It seems to contain the same information, and have the same dependencies as the Debian package `libavcodec-ffmpeg56`.  It may be as simple as a rename to keep inline with Ubuntu's naming scheme.

Here is the Ubuntu package [dependency list](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libavcodec-ffmpeg-extra56)

It seems the original `libavcodec-ffmpeg56` is from Debian.

Here is the Debian package [dependency list](https://packages.debian.org/sid/libavcodec-ffmpeg56)

If you're using the default Ubuntu sources list, then I would suggest just installing the standard `libavcodec-ffmpeg-extra56` package.  I think perhaps you have other sources enabled that would show you both?